# problem loading json to an object list in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a problem loading a JSON file to my object list,
I have a program that stores vehicles such as cars etc.
and I want to save it down to a JSON file and load the JSON file back up when I start the program again so the stored vehicles are loading in the packing list again. It stores to the list but when I load the program again it would not fill the List vehicles = new List(100);

EDIT:It will save the vehicles but it will not store it to the list when running the program again

```
public static void ReadParkingFile()          
    {

        string path = @"../../../Configfile/ParkingList.json";
        string jsonText = File.ReadAllText(path);
         List<Vehicle> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vehicle>>(jsonText).ToList();
       

    }
   
    public static void SaveToJasonFile(string vehicle)
    {
        string path = @"../../../Configfile/ParkingList.json";
         vehicle = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ParkingHouse.vehicles);
        File.WriteAllText(path, vehicle);


    }
```

Comment: have you tried `ParkingHouse.vehicles = data;` ? in `ReadParkingFile`

Comment: @TheGeneral that worked thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just need to assign the `data` reference to `ParkingHouse.vehicles`

```
string path = @"../../../Configfile/ParkingList.json";
string jsonText = File.ReadAllText(path);
List<Vehicle> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vehicle>>(jsonText).ToList();  
ParkingHouse.vehicles = data; // <- here
```